# Error when running npm "/usr/bin/node: 1: ELF: not found"

Tags: npm, ubuntu-22.04

Whenever i try to use nmp (`npm / npm install / sudo npm install / etc`) it output this:

```
/usr/bin/node: 1: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/node: 2: : not found
/usr/bin/node: 4: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I tried to reinstall it with
`sudo apt reinstall npm` and `sudo apt autoremove npm` `sudo apt install npm` but result is the same.

If it is important `apt` output this at the end of reinstalling

```
Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

User sessions running outdated binaries:
 myname @ /dev/tty1: bash[12777]
 root @ /dev/pts/0: apt[13552,13666], sh[13671]
 root @ /dev/tty1: init[12776]

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS from Microsoft Store

Comment: "whenever i try to use this command" -- What command?

Comment: npm/npm install/sudo npm install/etc

Comment: So just running the `npm` command gives that error? That information needs to be in the question.

Comment: I am getting the same error with Ubuntu from Microsoft Store and yes, it also happens for npm alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Node that can be installed with Ubuntu's `apt-get` command in WSL is currently outdated. These commands worked for me:

1. Remove any existing installations of Node.js or npm

   ```
   $ sudo apt remove npm
   ```
2. Install cURL and nvm

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install curl
   $ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
   ```
3. Close your current terminal, reopen it, and install Node

   ```
   $ nvm install --lts
   ```

Source: [Set up Node.js on WSL 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl)